# Compiler `#error` inline conditional on undefined variables throwing error on compile. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, winforms, ssh.net

I am not exactly sure how to word this problem, so hopefully the following details will help you understand what exactly is going on here. This is something I have never encountered before and it's peculiarity in code style is rather bizarre to me.

I downloaded the source for SSH.NET, and am attempting to merge the source of the component as part of a monolithic project, however there are numerous blocks such as the following one :

```
        public static int Read(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
#if FEATURE_SOCKET_SYNC
            var totalBytesRead = 0;
            var totalBytesToRead = size;

            socket.ReceiveTimeout = (int) timeout.TotalMilliseconds;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    var bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer, offset + totalBytesRead, totalBytesToRead - totalBytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                        return 0;

                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    if (IsErrorResumable(ex.SocketErrorCode))
                    {
                        ThreadAbstraction.Sleep(30);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                        throw new SshOperationTimeoutException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "Socket read operation has timed out after {0:F0} milliseconds.", timeout.TotalMilliseconds));

                    throw;
                }
            }
            while (totalBytesRead < totalBytesToRead);

            return totalBytesRead;
#elif FEATURE_SOCKET_EAP
            var receiveCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var sendReceiveToken = new BlockingSendReceiveToken(socket, buffer, offset, size, receiveCompleted);

            var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs
            {
                UserToken = sendReceiveToken,
                RemoteEndPoint = socket.RemoteEndPoint
            };
            args.Completed += ReceiveCompleted;
            args.SetBuffer(buffer, offset, size);

            try
            {
                if (socket.ReceiveAsync(args))
                {
                    if (!receiveCompleted.WaitOne(timeout))
                        throw new SshOperationTimeoutException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "Socket read operation has timed out after {0:F0} milliseconds.", timeout.TotalMilliseconds));
                }

                if (args.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                        throw new SocketException((int) args.SocketError);

                return sendReceiveToken.TotalBytesTransferred;
            }
            finally
            {
                // initialize token to avoid the waithandle getting used after it's disposed
                args.UserToken = null;
                args.Dispose();
                receiveCompleted.Dispose();
            }
#else
#error Receiving data from a Socket is not implemented.
#endif
        }
```

Which when trying to build, the compiler is getting stuck on the `#error Receiving data from a Socket is not implemented.` lines and throwing an exception `CS1029` which I can ignore, but my concern is more inline with why are all those conditions failing to be met (eg: `#elif FEATURE_SOCKET_EAP` ) and what can I do about it ?

Additionally, I get `Error  CS0161  'SocketAbstraction.Read(Socket, byte[], int, int, TimeSpan)': not all code paths return a value` as a result of the failover into the `#else` segment that is forcing the compiler to throw an exception with the inline message (eg : `#else <foo>` throws a CS1029 exception with `<foo>` as the description, and also blocks a return value in the method)

What can I do to correct these types of issues, and why on earth would anyone use inline compiler fail issues in this manner ?

Comment: Compilers don't throw exceptions, they emit errors. As for CS0161, since that happens only when you hit the `#error` directive, does it matter? By design, the code is supposed to fail to compile when neither of those `#define` symbols are defined. So what if an extra error occurs as well? You need to figure out which I/O model you want to use, and how the library you're compiling intended for you to declare that, and then just compile the code with the correct symbol defined as intended.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - thank you.  Not sure which symbol is better or what the difference is between them

Comment: I can't speak for the entire library, but in the code you show, the two control which form of the `Socket` API is used. One calls the `Receive()` method synchronously, which is blocking, while the other calls `ReceiveAsync()`, which is not. I can't speak to the correctness of the async version, because not all the code is visible, but it doesn't _look_ correct to me, as the containing method is supposed to be synchronous, but I see nothing in it that would properly wait for the asynchronous operation to complete before returning.

Comment: In any case, I'd say that if you are a person who a) feels a need to compile this library for your own purposes instead of using a version someone's already compiled for you, and b) don't know enough about the networking APIs to recognize the difference between synchronous code and asynchronous code, you should probably stick with the synchronous code, i.e. `FEATURE_SOCKET_SYNC`. You're going to have a hard enough time understanding and maintaining your branch of the library as it is, without having to deal with async code. (No offense intended here...I'm just trying to be realistic.)

Comment: _"do you have a problem with the concept of using open-source for what it is"_ -- I have no idea what your question means. Open source is fine. But if you're going to build and maintain your own branch, you need to have enough competence/experience to do that. If the library has different implementations controllable by compilation symbols, you need to stick with the ones that match your level of expertise.

Comment: @PeterDuniho solved this and other issues.  Embedding the code as part of a larger project instead of managing multiple libraries -- is good practice..  The code is recyclable, but without putting various versions of libs on the users computer.  Common practice for making portable applications as a single exe. Using elements from 3rd party OS projects - also common.  If that does not clarify for you, I am sure I can dig up a research paper or two to shove your direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your IDE for one of the specified conditional  compilation symbols.

If you are using Visual Studio:

- Open the project properties
- Go to tab "Build"
- Enter one of the values "FEATURE_SOCKET_EAP" or "FEATURE_SOCKET_SYNC" into the field "Conditional compilation symbols".

see also: https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/conditional-compilation/

Comment: Interesting, which would you recommend as I am unsure of the difference between those.

Comment: It depends if you need the sync or the async version. I would prefer the sync one ( "FEATURE_SOCKET_SYNC") if possible.

Comment: Thank you.  The end string was rather long set of flags to enable either sync or async, so I went with async as I prefer to not have my UI thread locked.  It was confusing as I have never seen build flags used this way before, so I was looking for constants (not build flags). Typically, I have seen both async and sync methods (aka, WebClient) built-in together, not exclusive of each other, so this is a very strange way to block out those areas. I can see how it may be useful in some scenarios, but in this one, it seems it could have been done without the conditions just supporting both methods